# Incorrect point movement (C-p, C-n) with org-indent-mode

Tags: point, visual-line-mode

#### Context:

- emacs 28.3
- doom
- org-mode
- visual-line-mode
- org-indent-mode

#### The problem:

Whenever type `C-p` or `C-n`, the point **most of the time** moves to the previous or next visual line. However, the column where the point jumps to seems to be arbitrary, and sometimes the point refuses to move up and I get a message "Beginning of buffer". I need to  move it sideways to "unlock it" and keep moving up.

If I disable org-indent-mode, it seems that the problem goes away. but now my lists are not nicely below their headlines.

Is this a known problem? Can it be fixed?

Comment: Using latest upstream Emacs and no Doom. I cannot reproduce it. Do you have an example file that you can pastebin somewhere?